# Does triac used for on/off purposes need RFI suppression?

Tags: triac, power-filtering

I noticed that in dimmer circuits using a triac there is a need for chokes to suppress RFI, Do on/off only circuits need the same?.. Please I need a detailed explanation or references to understand (not a yes or no answer)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm..how can I make this simple....

If you have a regular light switch and turn the light on and off, how much RFI does it make.... a bit, but not enough to worry about.

Now toggle the switch 100 to 120 times a second, depending on which part of the planet you live.... get the picture?

Dimmers work by doing exactly that at different points of cycle of the AC mains.

[image]

Each of those points in the waveform above where it switches off generate an RFI burst. This probably wont hurt the dimmer, but good luck listening to your AM radio.

As mentioned in the comments. Even using a triac as a switch, you are still better turning it on at the zero crossing point. It will create extremely little RFI, and also improve the TRIACs Life.

There is a suitable circuit here

[Hot Line Switching Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161133/why-do-we-prefer-zero-crossing-optotriacs-for-driving-triacs)

Comment: You mean both (dimming & on/off) emits RFI.. but dimming generates high frequency due to high cycles number per the second ?

Comment: That is correct. Or more accurately, dimming repetitively  generates a burst of RFI at the line frequency rate.

Comment: Additionally, on-off switches can be done very 'RFI friendly' by making them switch on and off at zero crossing.

Comment: "at the line frequency rate" what that mean please, and how can that burst of RFI effect the circuit?

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami While you can switch at a zero crossing, doing so defeats the purpose of a dimmer. Many dimmers work by turning on and off during the non-zero portions of the line cycle, which decreases power delivered to the load without wasting it by changing the voltage amplitude (ex. a resistor). It's sort of like PWM applied to an AC signal.

Comment: @HariGanti did you notice that the title of this topic is 'Switching ON and OFF'?

Comment: @HariGanti, ya but the OP isn't using it as a dimmer.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami (and Trevor but you can only tag one person) I read the question but missed the title... It also looks like the answer was updated to reflect zero-crossing too. My bad.

Comment: Claudio, If I'm controlling the triac's gate via an opto-coupler.. what I know is that the gate has a minimum voltage to be triggered.. how can I reach this zero crossing point

Comment: @msayed checkout this SO Page for an appropriate circuit http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161133/why-do-we-prefer-zero-crossing-optotriacs-for-driving-triacs

Comment: In a dimmer, it is the **quick change of current** in the wires when the triac switches that generates RFI. Long mains wires make nice antennas. If the triac switches at zero crossing, then the current starts at zero and rises smoothly with mains voltage, therefore there is no RFI problem.

Comment: BTW: This is why regular Triac dimmers are only good for resistive loads... like light bulbs. Zero V crossing is not the same as zero I crossing when trying to drive a motor or other inductive or capacative load.

Comment: Trevor, Thanks for the link & for keeping updating your answer.. I think I got it now, a triac at a zero crossing as a switch will not generates RF that can be harmful.

Comment: And inductive loads in a dimmer circuit (with a long wiring closed circuit) will make a nice antenna and a great radio transmitter in a shape of motor or whatever.. Is that correct and I understood it?

Comment: Yes, though the triac probably would not last too long.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 10 amps flowing in 100 feet of wire, that wire near but not next to its return path. Or the electrician may have routed the hot wire across a nearer path, and the HOT wire is nowhere near the RTN wire. At 1uH per meter (approximately), that 200 feet is 60uH of inductance. The energy stored, at peak currents, is $$1/2 * L * I^2$$ or using Peak Current, energy Joules is 0.5 * 60uH * (1.414*10)^2 = 30uH * 200 = 6milliJoules.

Now open that circuit---perhaps slowly by parting the metal contacts of the classic Levitor wallplate switch. Bring the contacts apart by 1micron, the contacts having area of 3mm*3mm. What happens? The energy now is within a resonant circuit, a circuit able to ring, with heavy copper wire and heavy metal contacts and an air gap. That air gap will become a plasma. Why?

Lets compute the voltage across that gap. We need the capacitance between the two 'plates' of the gap: $$Cparallelplate = Eo*Er*Area/Distance$$ We use our numbers: $$9e-12farad/meter * (1 for air) * 3mm * 3mm /1micron$$
$$Cpp =~ 1e-11Farad/meter * 9*10^-6meter^2 /1e-6meter = 9pF$$

What is the voltage across that 1micron gap? (we care, because dry air breaks down at 3,000 volts per millimeter; our breakdown will be 3 volts unless that gap has any tiny arc-points)
Capenergy  is $$1/2 * C * V^2 =0.006 joules$$ $$V = sqrt(0.006/0.000 000 000 005) = sqrt(1e^+9) = 30,000 volts$$

A plasma forms between the contacts, absorbing some of the energy and closing the circuit once again (what is resistance of a plasma?). The energy converts from electric-field to magnetic-field over 1/4 of a cycle of ringing. Back and forth. The plasma fades away, the energy during the ringing becomes electric field once again, and once again the distance between the contacts --- even as the contacts continue to move further apart --- is filled with a plasma.

This occurs at the ringing rate? 60uH and 5pF (originally), near 10MHz. As the contacts move apart, the frequency should increase but remnants of plasma may fill in a portion of the gap and increase that capacitance.

Summary: you are dealing with 30,000 volts and 10MHz and 5pF and 60uH.

Comment: Lots of numbers and none of them appropriate. The OP specifies a triac, which can only turn off when the current through it is zero. So no contacts, no plasma, no RF.

Comment: Great, although I need to study your answer to understand the whole image, I got the general idea .. for sure if you don't mind I will reply back with questions if I need to

Comment: That intense ringing and high-voltage is the environment for your TRIAC, because some of the circuits in your house will be switched with mechanical-contact motions. Or motors with old commutator rotators provide intense sparking.